# how to alternatively resolve and reject jquery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

is it possible to resolve a jquery deferred object and then to reject it, and then to resolve it again, etc.
And to trigger $.when each time it is resolved ?

I am trying this, but it doesn't work :

```
var bindHide = $.Deferred();
var bindShow = $.Deferred();
    if ($('#userdata').is(':hidden')) {
        bindShow.resolve();
    } else {
        bindHide.resolve();
    }
    //SHOW USERDATA
    $.when(bindShow).then(function() {
        bindShow.reject();
        $('#miniWeightLevel, #miniWeightLevelTextLayer').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {
            showUserdata();
            $('#miniWeightLevel, #miniWeightLevelTextLayer').unbind('vclick');
            bindHide.resolve();
        });
    });     
    //HIDE USERDATA
    $.when(bindHide).then(function() {
        bindHide.reject();
        $('#minifyCross').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {
            hideUserdata();
            bindShow.resolve();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using `.progress()` and `.notify()` methods. Everytime you call `notify()`, `.progress()` is triggered :

```
var logged=$.Deferred();

logged.notify();

logged.progress(function(){
//do what you need
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A given Deferred can only be rejected or resolved once.  And, since `$.when()` also returns a promise, it will only be rejected or resolved once too.  So, No it cannot work like you are asking it to.

Standard deferreds and promises are not designed to be a general purpose notification system which is how you are trying to use them.  jQuery's implementation has a notify feature which you could use for this, but the standards effort is moving that capability out of promises and it will be done differently.

It sounds to me more like you just need a notification system or custom events, not promises which are designed to be one-way.  They are resolved or rejected once and then never change again.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you provide code for what you suggesting ? thanks

Comment: @Louis - you would have to describe more about what your code is trying to accomplish (some sort of mini-specification) for me to attempt a complete redesign.  I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes indeed ! I am trying to be sure that the button `#minifyCross` has nothing bound to it when i click on the `#miniWeightLevel` button and vice versa

Comment: Louis, your're trying a wrong approach. Deferreds/Promises are not right for simple mutual button inhibition.